# Can a dockerfile make use of a data only container defined in the docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my docker-compose.yml file, I first define a service for a data-only container with a volume of /data:

```
data:
  image: library/ubuntu:14.04
  volumes:
    - /data
  command: tail -F /dev/null
```

I then have a second service that has a Dockerfile.

```
test:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
  volumes_from:
    - data:rw
  depends_on:
    - data
```

In that Dockerfile I want to write to that /data volume that comes from the data service (e.g., "RUN touch /data/helloworld.txt"). But when I run docker-compose up and then exec into test to look at the contents of /data, the directory is empty. If I wait to do "touch /data/helloworld.txt" until after the containers are running (e.g., via exec), then the file is present in the /data volume and accessible from either container.

Is there a way for a Dockerfile to make use of a volume from another container defined in docker-compose.yml?